# Whitelist network that can be used to download torrents

Tags: linux, networking, firewall

I want to make sure that torrents can not be downloaded on any other network except on my home network.

Is there a way to block network for certain program, based on current WiFi connection (like SSID or router MAC address)? To my knowledge this is not possible using firewalls.

Comment: No,  it's not. Just don't run the client when you're away from home. It shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: I have a bunch of scripts that run off the connection notification that the desktop manager receives. They identify the network using the MAC address of the gateway. Depending on network they trigger actions (I wrote them to login to a proxy and start a VPN to my company when I am on customer's premises). Such a script could kill the torrent client.